# Is there a way to do FTP-SSL with Perl's Net::FTP module?

Tags: perl, ssl, ftp

I'm working on a project that requires me to download files from FTP using Perl. I just found out that I've got the option to use FTP-SSL. It seems that this is just SSL encrypted FTP (similar to HTTP vs. HTTPS) and I should just have to send the "AUTH TLS" or "AUTH SSL" commands to the FTP server.

The question: is there a way to do this with the standard Net::FTP? I've checked the docs and the only thing I've found about it is use the "features" function to find out if the server supports it.

I found the Net::FTPSSL module on CPAN, but the author says sometimes the server does not receive the data that was sent. That doesn't sound like something I want to put into production.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: no.

From looking at the source of Net::FTP I'd say it's not possible to use SSL with it. I'd rather test if Net::FTPSSL works with the FTP server you're going to use your program with. If your program needs to be able to work with any FTP server, you might want to try and fix the module for those servers it doesn't work with and contribute your code to the original module.